# Best way to pass big List<T> from View to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, view, controller

I'm working on a View which has a List (Selected bool / ID string / Name string / Value decimal).

In this view user will select some items and submit form to save them in a database. But this List/ has approximately 2000 items and it is extremely slow.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(List<MyClass> list) {
    foreach (var item in list) {
        if (item.Checked) {
            // something
        }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @* TH /HTML *@

    @for (int r = 0; r < Model.Count(); r++)
    {
        <tr class="tr-clickable">
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => i[r].ID_User)
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(i => i[r].Checked)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Anything1)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Anything2)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => i[r].Value)</td>
        </tr>
    }

    @* HTML *@

    <div class="control-group margin-top-20 pull-right">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send Form" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Is there a better way to receive this List in my controller? I've been thinking to send list by jQuery-ajax and saving them one by one.

What do you guys think about it?

Comment: Does user has to select 2000 items ? That is terrible user experience.

Comment: you are checking if the sent item is Selected. Would it be possible for the Client only to send the selected items? I guess that would reduce the elements significantly. Sending them one by one would be even slower I think.

Comment: selecting from 2000 item is a bit cumbersome from use experience have look in to this link to how to pass ilst to controller http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET

Comment: @Shyju no, the user select aproximately 20/30/100 or all items.

Comment: Exactly which part is "extremely slow"?  It's most likely the form serialising the controls before POSTing.   Instead, you could have a `List<int> selectedIDs` and only include the ID control in the form, which the other parts of the item (name/value/etc) as html rather than form controls.  Another option is to put the IDs in a comma separated hidden form field which is updated via jquery.

Comment: @freedomn-m Got it, but how do I send the columns "ID" and "Value" at the same time? Is "extremely slow" when I do the submit, including my controller doesn't receive my list...

Comment: Why do you need to send id+value?  *only* send the IDs of the ones "selected" (as presented in your question) as the value is selected/not selected.  So, by definition, if it's not in your list of "selected" IDs, then it's not selected.

Comment: In my case, I must send the "ID" and the field "Values" of the selected itens. For example: "{ selected = true, id = 182, value = 548.45 }". Do you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was in jQuery Ajax:

```
    $('input[type="button"][data-submit]').click(function () {

        if (confirm('Anything?')) {

            var array = [];

            $('#table > tbody > tr').each(function () {
                var $tr = $(this);
                var usid = $tr.find('[data-usid]').val();
                var irvlr = $tr.find('[data-irvlr]').val();
                array.push({
                    User: usid,
                    Value: irvlr
                });
            });

            if (array.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'list': array }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        window.location.href = result.url;
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                alert('No items selected.');
            }

        }

    });
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

I think, your problem is not in "passing the list" but in "saving selected list items one by one". Sending 2k list from view to controller is not that heavy (well, it is, but it should still work not too slow). But if you perform N database operations for N selected items, this is where you have your bottle neck.

You have 2 options:

1. Save selected item as soon as user selects it.
2. Optimize your database operations by at least using single transaction for saving items.

Comment: Ok, but how can I send the List<T> only with the selected objects?

Comment: @AntônioFilho you can use jQuery: `$("#select-list").val()` if you want to send all selected values on form submit or you can use ajax to send values one by one when user selects item.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little confused. I'll have to do something like this? "        $.ajax({ url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")', type: 'POST', data: $("#select-list").serialize(), success: function (result) { alert('ok'); } });"

Comment: @AntônioFilho yes, something like that. Get values and then pass them using Ajax. But I would recommend to consider saving values when user selects them.

Comment: @AntônioFilho did it work for you? Do you still need help?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. I need some help. My difficulty is: I don't know how to pass a list of items with 2 attributes (ID / Value) to my controller without being "heavy". In that case, the list must be sent only when the user submit the form.

Comment: @AntônioFilho you should re-think your approach and remove submit button, instead you should use ajax to send items as user selects them.

Comment: Ya, I thought about that, but I also think the way that the user select one-by-one and think about them and then submit the form, is the best way to have a controlled process and precise. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @AntônioFilho yes, I see what you mean. When you do it this way, I think you get problems not with passing the list of items but with updating the database. So in this case I suggest you to look for ways to optimize your database insertion/update.

Comment: Yes, good tip. But the real problem is to pass the LIst<T> from View to Controller. If I 'put' a breakpoint at my controller, I don't get any response...

Comment: @AntônioFilho start from fixing your form tag. `Html.BeginForm()` it doesn't point to any controller action currently.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, I would first explore changing the entire user experience. If you are indeed in a situation where the user needs to select a large quantity of records one by one, I would use AJAX and submit them to a web api controller one by one as they're selected.

This has the added benefit of progressively saving progress and allowing the user to step away from the screen.

Comment: According with the selection I send the record by ajax, is it?

Comment: @AntônioFilho Correct, when the user selects an item from the list you can execute the ajax call to the server. If you just need to update the 'selected' bool on the server then I suggest sending just the identifier and new value for that field instead of the entire object.

Comment: Got it, but this is not my case. Because I need to send the entire object, on submit event. I cannot do one-by-one on each click, but I might do one-by-one in submit...